# How can i disconnect a user from my voice channel using menu discordjs

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to disconnect a specified user that is on my voiceChannel clicking on his username, this is my code:

```js
options = [];
    let perms = channel.members.map(c => c.user.tag)
                   
         for (let i = 0; i < perms.length; i++) {
                         
           options.push({
                    label: `${perms[i]}`,
                    value: `${i}`})     
}
const Select = new MessageSelectMenu()
.setCustomId(`disconnect`)
.setPlaceholder(`Members`)
 .addOptions(options)
.setMaxValues(1);

 const menu = new MessageActionRow()
.addComponents(Select);

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("BLUE" )
                .setDescription("Please select the user from the dropdown to disconnect.");
            interaction.reply({
                embeds: [embed],
                components: [menu], ephemeral: true
            })          

    
    
}
```

Discord.js v13.

Note: I'm looking for how i can disconnect users from my vc just by selecting their username. Ty.

Comment: In the interactionCreate event you receive the interaction object from where you can obtain the user's voice state and then disconnect him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed up this first part but you can use your way if you'd rather (you'd have to use a different way of getting the `member2disconnect`). Just seemed easier this way since the value would be the user's id rather than a integer.

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("BLUE")
    .setDescription("Please select the user from the dropdown to disconnect.");
const menu = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageSelectMenu()
        .setCustomId(`disconnect`)
        .setPlaceholder(`Members`)
        .setMaxValues(1),
    );

client.channels.cache.get(interaction.member.voice.channelId).members.forEach(member => {
    menu.components[0].addOptions({
        label: `${member.user.tag}`,
        value: member.user.id,
    });
});

return interaction.reply({
    embeds: [embed],
    components: [menu],
});
```

This next part goes in your `interactionCreate` listener

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (interaction.isSelectMenu()) {
        const selection = interaction.customId;

            if (selection == 'disconnect') {
                const member2disconnect = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.values[0]);
                member2disconnect.voice.disconnect();
                return interaction.message.edit({
                    content: `${member2disconnect} has been kicked from the VC.`,
                    embeds: [],
                    components: [],
                    ephemeral: true,
                });
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: The channel is the current channel where I am, define it like this let {channel} = interaction.member.voice

Comment: Answer has been updated

Comment: It works perfectly but there's a problem, it only shows my name and only 1 option, the other users that are connected don't appear among the options

Comment: I just improved my answer a bit (changed how it handles when a member is selected)

Comment: Than you so much, it works!!